# How to test Ktor host routing?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotest

Here is my setup:

```
fun Application.configure() {
    // ...
    routing {
        myApi()
    }
}
```

```
fun Route.myApi() {
    host("api.${environment?.config?.host}") {
        get("v1") { call.respondText("My api is here") }
    }
}
```

The configuration above should listen for requests on `api` subdomain on path `/v1` wherever the application is deployed.

```
ktor {
  deployment {
    host = "my.test"
    port = 8080
  }

  application {
    modules = [my.configuration.KtorKt.configure]
  }
}
```

When I start this application and try to GET `http://api.my.test:8080/v1` everything works as expected.

I am struggling with writing a test for this endpoint using Kotest and Ktor.

```
class ServerTest : FunSpec({
    test("my test") {
        testApplication {
            val response = client.get("http://api.my.test:8080/v1")
        }
    }
})
```

This resolves in the following error: `Can not resolve request to http://api.my.test:8080. Main app runs at localhost:80, localhost:443 and external services are`

How can I test this routing logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can send the `Host` header manually. Here is an example:

```
@Test
fun test() = testApplication {
    environment {
        config = MapApplicationConfig(listOf("ktor.deployment.host" to "localhost"))
    }
    application {
        routing {
            host("api.${environment?.config?.host}") {
                get("v1") { call.respondText("My api is here") }
            }
        }
    }

    val r = client.get("/v1") {
        header("host", "api.localhost")
    }
    assertEquals("My api is here", r.bodyAsText())
}
```